# In dialog, what pronoun forms go before the colon?

Tags: dialogue

What should I write before the colon in dialogue? Subject or object?

I: Do you love me?
He: Yes, I do.

Or

Me: Do you love me?
Him: Yes, I do.

Comment: What is this for? A screenplay? Something else?

Comment: Students' roleplay.. for practising dialogue/conversation in EFL class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a standard means of marking dialog, so you have some freedom here. The closest analogs I can think of are occasionally in fiction, where the author depicts a scene using play-style dialog tags and stage directions (e.g., *The Beautiful and the Damned* by F. Scott Fitzgerald).

So, that gives you some freedom here. The eighteenth century grammarians would, citing how dialog is marked in Latin drama, insist on I/He, but to my ear, with this dialog, Me/Him sounds more natural. A lot, however depends on the overall narrative voice and whether the narration is overall in a strict Johnsonian English.

Comment: What about if I extend the sentences like these... 1). I asked whether he loved me, 2). He said yes he did. Are they correct? If so.. Does it mean that I can use "I" and "He" in the dialogue?

Comment: @Teara - Extending them like that would make them no longer dialogue. You are just explaining an action. When written that way, it's no different then saying 3) I threw the ball over the fence, which obviously isn't dialogue. Dialogue usually refers to the exact words spoken. You didn't actually say, "Whether he loved me," so it isn't dialogue.